# Creating a box flap open effect using only CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I tried to create this effect using transitions. It should look like you are opening a box.

There are 2 problems:

1. The order in which the box closes is same as in which it opens. Is there anyway to close the box in reverse order of its opening so that the box goes back in the same state it was when closed?
2. The ends of the green and yellow flaps are hidden during transition because of the red and blue flaps, so it doesn't look 3D. Is there a way I can show all flaps in 3D way?

I would prefer if the solution was in pure CSS , no JavaScript please.

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  top: 170px;
  left: 170px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  perspective: 800px;
} 
#flap1, #flap2, #flap3, #flap4 {
  position: absolute;
}
#flap1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
#flap2 {
  left: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transition: transform 1s ease 0.3s;
}
#flap3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform 1s ease 0.6s;
}
#flap4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transition: transform 1s ease 0.9s;
}
#box:hover #flap1{
  transform: rotateY(-170deg);
}
#box:hover #flap2{
  transform: rotateY(170deg);
}
#box:hover #flap3{
  transform: rotateX(170deg);
}
#box:hover #flap4{
  transform: rotateX(-170deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="box">
      <div id="flap1"></div>
      <div id="flap2"></div>
      <div id="flap3"></div>
      <div id="flap4"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. I think you can't. Just add another class or something. 2. You can use css3 [`perspective`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For Question 1:**

If you give the delay in forward order for the `:hover` selectors and in the reverse order within default selectors, it will achieve the exact reverse animation.

**For Question 2:**

The fix and the explanation are as follows:

- For part of the transition duration, the green and yellow boxes don't look like they have 3D effect because there are a couple of elements with higher `z-index` which is being placed above. This prevents the stretched area (due to perspective rotate) from showing up and thus it looks like it's only 2D (while it actually is not). To overcome this, we need to instruct the browsers to preserve the 3D aspect of the transform. This is done using `transform-style: preserve-3d`.
- When we do the above, the flaps will all open with a 3D effect but near the start of the animation and its end, we will see a flicker on the blue flap when the transition actually starts and ends for the blue flap. It seems like this is because the `z-index` loses effect when 3D transform is used and there is a small amount of time between the losing of the `z-index` effect and starting of the `preserve-3D` effect during which the blue flap temporarily goes behind. To address this, the 3D equivalent of `z-index: 1` (which is, `translateZ(1px)`) is added. The translate in Z-axis brings the element closer by 1px to your eye and keeps it above the yellow and green flaps.
- Finally, despite all the above, there is a small glitch at the end of hover out animation, where the green flap shows through the blue flap. To overcome this, I had changed the delay timings a bit.

(*Contrary to what I originally mentioned, the `translateZ(0px)` is not required and can be removed.*)

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  top: 170px;
  left: 170px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  perspective: 800px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#flap1, #flap2, #flap3, #flap4 {
  position: absolute;
}
#flap1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateZ(1px);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform 1s 1.5s;
}
#flap2 {
  left: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateZ(1px);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transition: transform 1s ease 1s;
}
#flap3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform 1s ease 0.5s;
}
#flap4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
#box:hover #flap1 {
  transform: rotateY(-170deg) translateZ(1px);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
#box:hover #flap2 {
  transform: rotateY(170deg) translateZ(1px);
  transition: transform 1s ease 0.5s;
}
#box:hover #flap3 {
  transform: rotateX(170deg);
  transition: transform 1s ease 1s;
}
#box:hover #flap4 {
  transform: rotateX(-170deg);
  transition: transform 1s ease 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="flap1"></div>
  <div id="flap2"></div>
  <div id="flap3"></div>
  <div id="flap4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well solution to the first question was great, and although the 2nd solution works well, i dont understand how z-index is solving the problem....you see, if z-index of red and blue flaps is 1px, which is more than green and yellow box, shouldnt the 2nd problem still prevail as green and yellow boxes are still below red and blue box ? @Harry

Comment: @DhruvChadha: The `translateZ()` does almost the same as what `z-index` does for a 3D scenario. You are correct about the green and yellow still being below blue and red but adding a 3D transform results in layer creation (part of a complicated rendering process) which affects the behavior. Difficult to explain in comments. I will try to detail it in the answer. Give me sometime.

Comment: @DhruvChadha: I've added some extra explanation (and corrected a mistake from the original answer too :D). See if it helps :)

Comment: I must say I have never seen an explanation as good as this, but there is just one last thing regarding your 2nd point on translateZ, even without translateZ and even without z-index, i dont see any flicker (i removed both from the code) and it is working fine. I think preserve-3d itself does the job. I just put the red and blue divs after the green and yellow ones in the HTML. Just in case you want to check - https://jsfiddle.net/nt4me6ep/

Comment: Oh I thought you didn't want to change the order and that's why you had added the z-index. If the order can be changed then yes the z-index or translateZ aren't needed because elements lower down in the DOM will be placed above the earlier ones when they overlap and hence no need of extra setting to *make them stay above* :)